# Postgres get multiple rows into a single json object

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a users table with columns like `id`, `name`, `email`, etc. I want to retrieve information of some users in the following format in a single json object:

```
{
    "userId_1" : {"name" : "A", "email": "A@gmail.com"},
    "userId_2" : {"name" : "B", "email": "B@gmail.com"}
}
```

Wherein the users unique `id` is the key and a json containing his information is its corresponding value.

I am able to get this information in two separate rows using `json_build_object` but I would want it get it in a single row in the form of one single json object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use json aggregation functions:

```
select jsonb_object_agg(id, to_jsonb(t) - 'id') res
from mytable t
```

`jsonb_object_agg()` aggregates key/value pairs into a single object. The key is the `id` of each row, and the values is a jsonb object made of all columns of the table except `id`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=35e3e82d5e5a87b2826a61cc1ab96f79)**

Sample data:

```
id       | name | email      
:------- | :--- | :----------
userid_1 | A    | A@gmail.com
userid_2 | B    | B@gmail.com
```

Results:

```
| res                                                                                                    |
| :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| {"userid_1": {"name": "A", "email": "A@gmail.com"}, "userid_2": {"name": "B", "email": "B@gmail.com"}} |
```

Answer (score 1):

try -

```
select row_to_json(col) from T
```

link below might help https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT json_object(array_agg(id), array_agg(json::text)) FROM (
SELECT id, json_build_object('name', name, 'email', email) as json
                     FROM users_table
) some_alias_name
```

If your id is not of text type then you have to cast it to text too.

Comment: Thanks, gives the desired output.